# Возможно ли на серверной стороне следить за балансом mastercard?

Tags: node.js, api

В моём случае серверная сторона на node.
Есть страница пользователя, на ней я хочу видеть баланс на моей чп карте и конечно обновлять его например каждые n часов.
Возможно ли реализовать подобное, есть ли у mastercard нужное api?

Comment: Если банк, выпустивший карту, предоставляет соответствующий API (что очень маловероятно, ибо потенциальная уязвимость), то можно.

Comment: @Yaant, т.е. вопрос скорее к, например приват банку, чем к mastercard?

Comment: Вообще, у MasterCard есть [API](https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/display/api/API). Вот только не похоже, что там есть методы для проверки баланса.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, В том то и дело. Тоже подходящего ничего не нашёл, вот и решил спросить, может кто сталкивался.

Comment: @UFleming Именно. Информация о балансе есть только непосредственно в банке.

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо, круг поиска сузился )